# How can I change my BIOS startup screen? How can I backup my BIOS?

Tags: backup, bios, bootloader, restore, uefi

I want to know all the safe ways to change the bios startup screen for my lenovo Y500.

Instead of lenovo's logo can I have a GIF? Can I have sound with it? Can I time it such that the screen is blank when loading starts? What are different ways I can experiment with it safely?

How do I go about backing up and restoring the BIOS if everything doesn't go as planned? What would I lose if this happens?

Comment: I've found something here: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/f3af0be8-1853-46eb-a929-cdf6de6463a9/windows-8-custom-boot-logo?forum=w8itproinstall

Comment: Umm... Well, I... This is my first ever computer post actually, I hope you understand, I can't even know what is happening if SO doesn't explain it to me directly.

Answer (score 2):

You can't have custom images for a bios boot screen.... The most you can do is enable the boot logo or disable it but customizing would never work.  Also most mediums of storage wouldn't be available to the bios before post so no way to even store an image for this..

Comment: And if I disable it I'd have the BOOT sequence at startup, yes? How can I do that?

Comment: You can either have the boot sequence shown or have it hidden. Whichever you prefer.

Comment: Yeah, but, how do I go about it.

Comment: Some firmwares (e.g. my old ASUS desktop) _do_ allow uploading custom logos.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, (almost) all stock BIOS Flashing utilities are also BIOS Readers in disguise. Case studies:-

DISCLAIMER : All tips and tricks listed have not been listed properly as they from my personal experience. Please look into all the paragraphs for an appropriate solution.

DISCLAMER 2 : After editing the BIOS file, always ensure that is either smaller than or equal to the capacity of your BIOS chip. To know that, open our computer, search online, etc. Even the best piece of software will barely help with this.

> Insyde :
>       Computer in use : Lenovo G560
>       Downloaded the latest BIOS update and the flash utility from the official Lenovo site. Curious, I opened the platform.ini file in notepad, turns out it stores all the parameters for the flash utility. Under the `[Options]` section, changed the `Flag` value to 1 and Boom! A quick and easy GUI way to change all the other parameters in the file, such backing up the current BIOS before flashing (you can actually backup the BIOS and then cancel the flash process.), 'patching' the boot logo, etc. You can also download the Insyde official BIOS editor [here](http://www.mediafire.com/file/0zg6966v21hkw36/EzH2O.zip)(referenced to by [this](http://www.mediafire.com/file/0zg6966v21hkw36/EzH2O.zip) lenovo forum) for more comprehensive and detailed use and stuff.
>
> American Megatrends:
>       Computer in use : ECS G41T-M7
>       They literally have a `Save...`
>    option in the flasher. And they actually provide a utility to change the logo [here](https://ami.com/products/bios-uefi-tools-and-utilities/bios-uefi-utilities/). If that doesn't work, a few minutes of google-ing should satisfy you.
>
> Pheonix:
>       Computer in use : HP-dv1743tu
>       Download the utility. It may not have save button or a parameters file but you should check if the .exe file you double-clicked is the one that is running. Use Task Manager for that purpose. There is a good enough possibility that the original .exe file exracted itself and ran another .exe file that has a parameter file with it, though it will be in the Temp folder so it may take sometime to isolate it. If it really is a standalone execuable or there is no parameters file, download another utility from www.bios-mods/downloads/ and unzip it. Copy over the .dll, .sys, and .vxd files over to the new utility's folder, rename as required and viola, it should run perfectly. If it doesn't, again, a few minutes of google-ing always helps.

That covers the biggies, I presume. If any more help is required, check the above-mentioned site www.bios-mods.com/downloads/ and the omniscient Google Baba.